# JavaScript library for stretching divs

Tags: javascript

I need advice. I need to make something like a rich text editor but only for div tags. User can move div, change place of two divs with drag and drop (add gravity), stretch width and height of div with mouse pointer. All divs which can be edited is in one parent div. My question is, because I am new to JavaScript, which library is the best for these kinds of things, has anyone done something similar with some library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has the [`resizable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good idea to combine methods. For example you can use hte HTML5 features (draggable=true), combined with plain JavaScript and CSS3 (resize: both;).

Have a look at this [article](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/) for the drag and drop, and at [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/) *preview* of CSS3's resize.